# In Wagtail, how to prevent page deletion by editors, or set a minimum number of pages of a kind

Tags: django, wagtail

The site we developed has 2 type of pages, let's call them...

- "Static" ones: Home, Contact, About us, the general Catalog page, the general Blog page...
- "Dynamic" ones: each Collection in the catalog, each Blog entry.

We, as developers, provide the final customer with all the structure for the Static ones, meaning they don't have to create them at all. There are many reasons for it but mainly because the site structure counts on these pages to always exist (in a Published state btw, but let's leave that aside).

And we let and teach the client's editor to do, among other stuff..

- Just edit the existing "static"pages.
- Create, edit and delete child pages in Catalogue and Blog.

But we want to prevent them from deleting any of the other pages. Things might blow up, like, the Home shows some information collected from some of the other sections etc... but mainly because it doesn't make sense in our situation, that is: **the only case in which they might delete one of the "static" pages is by accident**.

If they really want to delete any of these pages, that's a decision design that will involve other people (managers, designers and developers) and many steps will be required to execute that, including the release of a new version.

We're already preventing the user from creating pages that they shouldn't, by setting the `max_count = 1` to those pages. We could achieve the same with the "Create" permission in Editor group, ofc.

It would be great to have a `min_count` property, or even better, a `min_published_count` one, but there isn't.

According to [this issue](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/2907)'s discussion, controlling that at a permission-level is not and will not be an option.

I imagine a workaround will be to intercept the `delete()` method of the model, but this might not prevent bulk deletion I guess, but well, I'll give it a try. It feels like an awkward workaround though...

Anyone else in a similar situation? Or any idea about what would be the cleanest approach to that situation?

Many many thanks in advance :hug:

*As a side note, clarify that we're consciously choosing to limit as much as possible the power of the editors because we believe this brings them the best experience thanks to the clarity and safety that this limitation comes with.
In contrast, other systems in which they face an immense amount of options and power, leads them to a daunting learning curve and the constant fear of breaking the site by accident. Deleting a page, by instance, is greatly destructive, will leave their company's page in a bad or unusable state and the only solution will usually be to restore a database backup.*

**Edit: partial solution using hooks**

Thanks to Robert's answer, I've been trying to achieve it using hooks.

```py
# wagtail_hooks.py
from wagtail import hooks


@hooks.register('construct_page_action_menu')
def remove_disabled_actions(menu_items, request, context):
    specific_page = context["page"].specific
    if not specific_page.is_submitable:
        menu_items[:] = [item for item in menu_items if item.name != 'action-submit']
    if not specific_page.is_unpublishable:
        menu_items[:] = [item for item in menu_items if item.name != 'action-unpublish']


@hooks.register('construct_page_listing_buttons')
def remove_page_listing_button_item(buttons, page, page_perms, context=None):
    specific_page = page.specific
    if not specific_page.show_more_dropdown_in_list_actions:
        buttons.pop() # removes the last button, which is the 'more' dropdown.
```

```py
# models.py
class BasePage(Page):
    [ ... fields etc. ]
    
    is_submitable = False
    is_unpublishable = False
    # Removing this dropdown is also removing the "Delete" page option that it
    # contains. If you enable it, make sure that you actually pretend to give
    # the editor access to every action it provides!
    show_more_dropdown_in_list_actions = False
```

This solution lacks of:

- Either entirely removing the bulk actions buttons from the list view, or deciding which of its buttons to include.
- From the page editing view, to remove the *Delete*, *Unpublish* and other options from the contextual menu from the three dots at the top of the page, by the breadcrumb.

Therefore so far is useless because the editor can still perform the actions in some ways, but it's a step forward.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
#_____________________________________________________________________________
class HomePageMixin(
    MenuCaptionMixin,
    ShowTocMixin,
    ImageMixin,
    ShowImageMixin,
    SubTitleMixin,
    TitlesColorMixin,
    AsideMixin,
    Page,
    RevisionMixin
    ):

    max_count = MAX_SITES
    is_movable = False
    is_unpublishable = False
    @property
    def is_copyable(self):
        return self.get_parent().specific.can_add_homepage

    @property
    def is_deletable(self):
        return self.get_parent().get_children().count() > 1
    
    
    
#_____________________________________________________________________________
@hooks.register('register_custom_page_listing_more_buttons')
def custom_page_listing_more_buttons(page, page_perms, is_parent=False, next_url=None):
    specific_page = page.specific
    admin_display_title = page.get_admin_display_title()
    
    if page_perms.can_move() and specific_page.is_movable:
        yield Button(
            _('Move'),
            reverse('wagtailadmin_pages:move', args=[page.id]),
            attrs={"title": _("Move page '{}'").format(admin_display_title)},
            priority=10
        )
    if page_perms.can_copy() and specific_page.is_copyable:
        url = reverse('wagtailadmin_pages:copy', args=[page.id])
        if next_url:
            url += '?' + urlencode({'next': next_url})
        yield Button(
            _('Copy'),
            url,
            attrs={'title': _("Copy page '{}'").format(admin_display_title)},
            priority=20
        )
    if page_perms.can_delete() and specific_page.is_deletable:
        url = reverse('wagtailadmin_pages:delete', args=[page.id])
        # After deleting the page, it is impossible to redirect to it.
        if next_url == reverse('wagtailadmin_explore', args=[page.id]):
            next_url = None
        if next_url:
            url += '?' + urlencode({'next': next_url})
        yield Button(
            _('Delete'),
            url,
            attrs={'title': _("Delete page '{}'").format(admin_display_title)},
            priority=30
        )
    if page_perms.can_unpublish() and specific_page.is_unpublishable:
        url = reverse('wagtailadmin_pages:unpublish', args=[page.id])
        if next_url:
            url += '?' + urlencode({'next': next_url})
        yield Button(
            _('Unpublish'),
            url,
            attrs={'title': _("Unpublish page '{}'").format(admin_display_title)},
            priority=40
        )
    if page_perms.can_view_revisions():
        yield Button(
            _('Revisions'),
            reverse('wagtailadmin_pages:history', args=[page.id]),
            attrs={'title': _("View page history for '{}'").format(admin_display_title)},
            priority=50
        )
    if is_parent:
        yield Button(
            _('Sort menu order'),
            '?ordering=ord',
            attrs={'title': _("Change ordering of child pages of '{}'").format(admin_display_title)},
            priority=60
        )
```

Comment: Hi Robert, many thanks, although this code doesn't work as-is, and this approach would only let you add more buttons but not remove the existing ones, it led me in the right direction; I was not aware that hooks were used to control this. I'm updating the question with a partial solution derived from your post.